# Changing the control Id to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, syntax

I need to change the below code:

```
 $("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_3c1ba10a_23ec_4ab5_b303_18f8bd7ee7e7_ctl00_btnAdd").attr("disabled", true);
```

To this:

```
var ControlID = "#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_3c1ba10a_23ec_4ab5_b303_18f8bd7ee7e7_ctl00_btnAdd"

$(ControlID).attr("disabled", true);
```

But the above one not working .. what is the error ?

Comment: Your code is correct. Albeit ugly.

Comment: Works fine here witth **attr:** demos http://jsfiddle.net/2MKX6/1/ & with **prop** http://jsfiddle.net/2MKX6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it isn't working in either case. Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`, to disable the element.

```
var ControlID = "#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_3c1ba10a_23ec_4ab5_b303_18f8bd7ee7e7_ctl00_btnAdd"
$(ControlID).prop("disabled", true);
```

*Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The `.prop()` method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the `.attr()` method. The `.val()` method should be used for getting and setting value.*

Source: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('<%:Control.ControlID%>').attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: i cannot comprehend what is not working, you need to provide more context to the "this is not working"

Comment: does the selector return the correct element? have you checked it using firebug or any other DOM inspector ? are there any javascript related error? what version of .net you are using ? if its 4 then you can make the id of your control static ...